# How to get HorizontalScrollView to scroll with one custom View child

Tags: android, scrollview

I'm not quite sure how to ask this but I need a scrollview that will scroll with an amplitude visualizer as it records audio. EDIT: To be clear, the ScrollView is not scrolling even with touches and gestures.

Here's a screenshot of the app with the custom view. The red bars show the average amplitude of a second.
[image]

The bars fill from left to right, but when it reaches the edge it does not scroll.

Here's the XML for the HorizontalScrollView and the AudioVisualizer view:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/hsv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <com.blueteam.audiotes.AudioVisualizer
        android:id="@+id/visualizer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Here's the code for the AudioVisualizer element:

```
package com.blueteam.audiotes;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by tanner on 3/21/17.
 */

public class AudioVisualizer extends View {

    private final int BAR_WIDTH = 10;
    private final int BAR_STARTING_POINT = 0;
    private final int BAR_SPACE = 2;
    private final int BAR_BOTTOM = 200;
    private final int BAR_MINIMUM_HEIGHT = 20;

    private ArrayList<Rect> bars;
    private Paint paint;
    private ArrayList<Tag> tags;

    public AudioVisualizer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        bars = new ArrayList<Rect>();
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        for(Rect r : bars)
            canvas.drawRect(r.left, r.top, r.right, r.bottom, paint);
    }

    public void addBar(int height) {
        if (height < BAR_MINIMUM_HEIGHT)
            height = BAR_MINIMUM_HEIGHT;
        else if (height > BAR_BOTTOM)
            height = BAR_BOTTOM;
        bars.add(new Rect(BAR_STARTING_POINT + bars.size() * (BAR_SPACE + BAR_WIDTH),
            BAR_BOTTOM - height,
            (BAR_STARTING_POINT + bars.size() * (BAR_SPACE + BAR_WIDTH)) + BAR_WIDTH,
            BAR_BOTTOM));
    }

}
```

I tried setting the AudioVisualizer width to something like 2000 just to see if it would scroll when the child was clearly larger than the ScrollView, but it still didn't work.

I'm guessing I'm missing something simple.

Answer (score 2):

Change your xml like this:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/hsv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <com.blueteam.audiotes.AudioVisualizer
        android:id="@+id/visualizer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

And whenever you `addBar` do this:

```
audioVisualizer.addBar(10);
parentHsv.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT);
```

Comment: Sorry I was not clear in the original post. I can't scroll even with touch gestures. I added this but it didn't change anything. However you did solve another problem I was having.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I didn't override onMeasure. Here's my code:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int width = (BAR_WIDTH + BAR_SPACE) * bars.size();
    setMeasuredDimension(width, MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec));
}
```

I also needed to call v.requestLayout() before v.invalidate() to update the size.